# How to read a file containing strings and integers into an ArrayList and sort by integer?

Tags: java, algorithm, file, arraylist, selection-sort

I'm trying to read from a text file containing a list of names and grades, organized by line, i.e.:

David Smith 84

Susan L Potter 100

...

Then store them (by line) in an ArrayList, and sort that ArrayList by the students' grade using a selection sort algorithm, however I've tried multiple different ways to code this and every edit seems to prompt another error (I'm extremely new to programming). This is what I currently have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {
    private static void sort(ArrayList<String> list) {
        int pFill;
        int pTest;
        int pSmallest;
        String temp;
        for (pFill = 0; pFill < list.size(); pFill++) {
            pSmallest = pFill;
            for (pTest = pFill + 1; pTest < list.size(); pTest++) {
                if (pTest < pSmallest) {
                    pSmallest = pTest;
                }
            }
            temp = list.get(pSmallest);
            list.set(pSmallest, list.get(pFill));
            list.set(pFill, temp);
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String fileName = "students.txt";
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            while(input.ready()){
                list.add(input.readLine());
            }
            input.close();
            sort(list);
            System.out.println(list);
        } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a student object to hold name and grade separately. Once you have added all the data into list you can directly use list.sort() method by using [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) but in your case you want to write selection sort that's why you have to write another method to do selection sort.

```java
package com.stackovflow.problems;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Grades {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String fileName = "students.txt";
            try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
                while(input.ready()){
                    String line = input.readLine().trim();
                    String name = line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf(' '));
                    int grade = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ')+1));
                    list.add(new Student(name, grade));
                }
                input.close();
                selectionSort(list);
                System.out.println(list);
            } catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private static void selectionSort(ArrayList<Student> list) {
            int pFill;
            int pTest;
            int pSmallest;
            Student temp;
            for (pFill = 0; pFill < list.size(); pFill++) {
                pSmallest = pFill;
                for (pTest = pFill + 1; pTest < list.size(); pTest++) {
                    Student pTestStudent = list.get(pTest);
                    Student pSmallestStudent = list.get(pSmallest);
                    if (pTestStudent.getGrade() < pSmallestStudent.getGrade()) {
                        pSmallest = pTest;
                    }
                }
                if(pSmallest!=pFill) {
                    temp = list.get(pSmallest); 
                    list.set(pSmallest, list.get(pFill));
                    list.set(pFill, temp);
                }
            }

        }
    }

//This class is to hold line data in your students.txt file
class Student{
    private String name;
    private int grade;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", grade=" + grade + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy if you declare a `Student` class with 2 fields `name` and `age`. And you can make the `Student` class implement `Comparable` and compare on the basis of grade. It will look something like this:

```java
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private final String name;
    private final int grade;
    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        return Integer.compare(this.grade, grade);
    }
}
```

To populate the `Student` object you will need to split the `String` and extract the name and grade, and then call `new Student(name, grade)`.

In your `sort` method you can pass a `List<Student>` where you can compare 2 students (as `Student implements Comparable<Student>`) by calling something like `s1.compareTo(s2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the list of student. You can use Comparator  to do this.

```
List<Student> sorted=list.sort(Comparator.comparing(p-> p.getGrade()));
```

Or use stream api

```
List<Person> result =list.stream().sorted((p1, p2)>p1.getGrade().compareTo(p2.getGrade())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate Student.java file in the same folder to hold the Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final int grade;
    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getGrade(){
        return grade;
    }
}
```

Then split each line by space and set the first tokens as the name and the last as the grade, then use Comparator to sort the ArrayList of Student Objects:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Grades {
    private static ArrayList<Student> sort(ArrayList<String> list) {

        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        String name = "";
        int grade;

        for (String line : list) {
            String[] splitted = line.split("\\s+");

            for(int i = 0;i< splitted.length-1;i++){
                name += splitted[i] + " ";
            }
            grade = Integer.parseInt(splitted[splitted.length-1]);
            students.add(new Student(name,grade));
            name = "";

        }
        students.sort(Comparator.comparing(student-> student.getGrade()));

        return students;

    } 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String fileName = "students.txt";
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            while(input.ready()){
                list.add(input.readLine());
            }
            input.close();
            ArrayList<Student> sortedStudents = sort(list);

            for (Student currentStudent : sortedStudents) 
                System.out.println(currentStudent.getName() + currentStudent.getGrade());                


        } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```